# jQuery hovering over one div to trigger changes in another div

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

When I hover over the text, both the text and the css icon are triggered as they should be.

However, when I hover over the css icon only the css icon is triggered when both the icon and text should be as in the previous instance.

What is wrong with my jQuery that it doesn't work both ways?

http://jsfiddle.net/jaoyebc8/

html

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<span class="twitter-underline-1">Just some filler text</span>

<span title="Click to Tweet"><i id="twitter-1" class="fa fa-twitter"></i></span>
```

css

```
.twitter-underline-1 {
border-bottom: 1px dotted #E0E0E0;
}

.twitter-underline-1:hover {
border-bottom: 1px solid #4099FF;
}

#twitter-1 {
padding-top: 0px;
font-size: 40px;
color: #E0E0E0;
margin-left: 55px;
}

#twitter-1:hover {
color: #4099FF;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.twitter-underline-1').mouseover(function(){
    $('.twitter-underline-1').css('border-bottom: 1px solid', '#4099FF');
    $('#twitter-1').css('color', '#4099FF');
});
$('.twitter-underline-1').mouseout(function(){
    $('.twitter-underline-1').css('border-bottom: 1px dotted', '#E0E0E0');
    $('#twitter-1').css('color', '#E0E0E0');
});
$('#twitter-1').mouseover(function(){
    $('#twitter-1').css('color', '#4099FF');
    $('.twitter-underline-1').css('border-bottom: 1px solid', '#4099FF');
});
$('#twitter-1').mouseout(function(){
    $('#twitter-1').css('color', '#E0E0E0');
    $('.twitter-underline-1').css('border-bottom: 1px dotted', '#E0E0E0');
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error in css. Check this out: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jaoyebc8/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.twitter-underline-1').mouseover(function(){
        $('.twitter-underline-1').css('border-bottom',' 1px solid #4099FF');
        $('#twitter-1').css('color', '#4099FF');
    });
    $('.twitter-underline-1').mouseout(function(){
        $('.twitter-underline-1').css('border-bottom','1px dotted #E0E0E0');
        $('#twitter-1').css('color', '#E0E0E0');
    });
    $('#twitter-1').mouseover(function(){
        $('#twitter-1').css('color', '#4099FF');
        $('.twitter-underline-1').css('border-bottom','1px solid #4099FF');
    });
    $('#twitter-1').mouseout(function(){
        $('#twitter-1').css('color', '#E0E0E0');
        $('.twitter-underline-1').css('border-bottom',' 1px solid #E0E0E0');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you can target any other element (as soon as the target element is at the same or lower level of the trigger element, you cannot target parent elements with CSS) only with css like so:

```
#trigger-element:hover #target-element { /* hover effect rules */ }
```

Added some CSS rules and removed much more js lines

Check the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jaoyebc8/5/)

```
.twitter-underline-1 {
border-bottom: 1px dotted #E0E0E0;
}

.twitter-underline-1.hover,
.twitter-underline-1:hover {
border-bottom: 1px solid #4099FF;
}
.twitter-underline-1:hover ~ .twit-span #twitter-1 {
color: #4099FF;
}

#twitter-1 {
padding-top: 0px;
font-size: 40px;
color: #E0E0E0;
margin-left: 55px;
}

.twit-span:hover #twitter-1 {
color: #4099FF;    
}
```

Comment: Nice solution - you can even make it less JS by changing to: $('.twit-span').hover(function() {
    $('.twitter-underline-1').toggleClass('hover');
});

Answer (score 0):

Why not try adding a class using [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) and [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/):

```
$('.twitter-underline-1').hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("hover");
    $('#twitter-1').toggleClass("hover");
});

$('#twitter-1').hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("hover");
    $('.twitter-underline-1').toggleClass("hover");
});
```

Change your CSS to use the `.hover` class:

```
.twitter-underline-1.hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4099FF;
}

#twitter-1.hover {
    color: #4099FF;
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jaoyebc8/4/)